# .gitolite.rc what does this files do?

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm trying to understand what the file `.gitolite.rc`
I searched a lot in the internet and could not file an explanation and a real example.

What does it do and how do I configure it?

Comment: Does [this](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc.html) help?

Answer (score 0):

The [gitolite.rc file (doc)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc.html) is read by gitolite for various settings.

> You can always get a default copy for your current version by running `gitolite print-default-rc`.

You can also read the comments in [`src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L501`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/f480dbf9275b7a82ccbff208f2925a25864432b9/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L501).

Once gitolite is installed, you will find it in `~/.gitolite.rc`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.gitolite.rc` file is the configuration file for Gitolite. Most day-to-day administration can be done via the gitolite-admin repository, but for more complicated problems, you might need to edit this file.

You can simply leave the file alone if you don't really know what to do with it.

The reason for not putting this file into the gitolite-admin repository is simply a security consideration: In this file, you can do more dangerous settings, like enable shell access. In most setups, not everyone allowed to write the gitolite-admin repository should also be allowed to get themselves shell access.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the official Gitolite documentation on the subject:

http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#rc

Essentially it is Perl code.

> The rc file is perl code, but you do NOT need to know perl to edit it. Just mind >the commas, use single quotes unless you know what you're doing, and make sure >the brackets and braces stay matched up!
>
> As you can see there are 3 types of variables in it:
>
> A lot of simple variables (like UMASK, GIT_CONFIG_KEYS, etc.).
>      A hash or two (like ROLES).
>      And one large list of features to be enabled (ENABLE).
>
> This page documents only some of them; for most of them it's best to look in the >actual rc file or in each of their individual documentation files around; start >with "non-core" gitolite. If a setting is used by a command then running that >command with '-h' may give you additional information.

To read more:
http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#rc

Answer (score 0):

This is you `gitolite` setting for your project.

---

http://gitolite.com/gitolite/files.html

> Gitolite creates and uses the following files and directories:
>
> ```
> ~/repositories -- the actual (bare) repositories are here
> ~/.gitolite.rc -- configuration parameters that must be done directly on the  server
> ~/.gitolite -- gitolite's "working" directory.   
> This contains everything else that gitolite needs. 
> (Warning: you're not supposed to fiddle with the files and directories within;
> ```
>
> instead, make changes in a clone of the gitolite-admin repository and push, and those appear magically here).

---

http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc-33.html

> the v3.0 to v3.3 "rc" file ($HOME/.gitolite.rc)
>
> ...
>
> As before, it is designed to be the only thing unique to your site for most setups. What is new is that it is easy to extend it when new needs come up, without having to touch core gitolite.
>
> **The rc file is perl code, but you do NOT need to know perl to edit it.
>
>   Just mind the commas, use single quotes unless you know what you're doing, and make sure the brackets and braces stay matched up!**
>
> Please look at the ~/.gitolite.rc file that gets installed when you setup gitolite. As you can see there are 3 types of variables in it:
>
> ```
> simple variables (like UMASK)
> lists (like POST_COMPILE, POST_CREATE)
> hashes (like ROLES, COMMANDS)
> ```
>
> While some of the variables are documented in this file, many of them are not.
>
> Their purposes are to be found in each of their individual documentation files around; start with "non-core" gitolite. If a setting is used by a command then running that command with '-h' may give you additional information.